# Add sp parameter sql server without modifying the stored procedure request

Tags: sql-server

I have a sample stored procedure named `SPExample` .

I want to add a parameter named `TestParam` to this stored procedure without using this syntax

```
Alter PROCEDURE SPExample
    @TestParamint
AS
BEGIN
... 
END
```

Is there a syntax like: `Alter PROCEDURE SPExample Add parameter ...` or any other alternative?

Comment: No, you have to alter procedure and change its definition in order to add another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

NO you can not

**Detailed answer:**

Alter procedure has 3 different syntax as below:

SQL Server Syntax:

```
ALTER { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ]   
[ { @parameter [ type_schema_name. ] data_type }   
    [ VARYING ] [ = default ] [ OUT | OUTPUT ] [READONLY]  
] [ ,...n ]   
[ WITH <procedure_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
[ FOR REPLICATION ]   
AS { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }  
[;]  

<procedure_option> ::=   
[ ENCRYPTION ]  
[ RECOMPILE ]  
[ EXECUTE AS Clause ]
```

SQL Server CLR Stored Procedure Syntax:

```
ALTER { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ]   
[ { @parameter [ type_schema_name. ] data_type }   
    [ = default ] [ OUT | OUTPUT ] [READONLY]  
] [ ,...n ]   
[ WITH EXECUTE AS Clause ]  
AS { EXTERNAL NAME assembly_name.class_name.method_name }  
[;]
```

Azure SQL Database Syntax:

```
ALTER { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name   
[ { @parameter [type_schema_name. ] data_type }   
[ VARYING ] [= default ] [ [ OUT [ PUT ]   
] [,...n ]   
 [ WITH <procedure_option> [ , ...n ] ]   
 [ FOR REPLICATION ]
 AS   
 { <sql_statement> [...n ] }  
[;]  

<procedure_option> ::=   
[ ENCRYPTION ]  
[ RECOMPILE ]   
[ EXECUTE_AS_Clause ]   

<sql_statement> ::=   
{ [ BEGIN ] statements [ END ] }
```

Note that in all 3 syntaxes above, `sql_statement` is one of the mandatory parts of the syntax. Parts inside `[` and `]` are optional, Read more about Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

As you see in the above syntaxes there is not any syntax like one you requested.

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cant add parameter with out altering stored proc. A closer option would be to use Default Parameters in case if you dont want to edit your stored procedure when you want to add  new Parameter..

this goes something like this..

```
create proc usp_test
(
@param1 int=4,
@param2 int =null,
@param3 int =null
)
as
Begin

END
```

Those parameters with null wont be  having any impact